# Unable to list entries in site where section type is not available

Tags: entries, craft4, plugin-neo

I am using Craft CMS 4 latest. I have a NeoSections field that among others contain a field called `entries` that has one or more entries in it.

I am running a multisite with 8 sites in 4 site groups.

When I add entries from Site B to the NeoSections `entries`-field on Site A, the template is not displaying any entries when previewing the entry on Site A (entries|length == 0).

When I enable the entry type on Site A, the entries now show up, but their links point to somewhere on Site A - which is not what I want, as I want to link to the entries on Site B.

Any idea why this happens, and how to mitigate, so I am able to add entries that belong to other sites and have the links open on the proper site? I don't really want to make the entry type available on Site A.

[image: List of sites where entry type "Product" is available]